# Как отключить изменение области видимости при поиске по организациям

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Доброго времени суток,

нужно вывести список организаций, но при получении результата всегда идет подстройка области видимости под результаты. Можно ли как-то отключить?

Из доки: "Для поиска по организациям не работают следующие опции: «noPlacemark», «noCentering», «noSelect», «strictBounds», «kind»"

Использую, как в примере, `searchControl.search('Шоколадница')`

https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo

Comment: приведите пожалуйста пример какой у вас запрос требуется и какой вы получаете

Comment: https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search/v2/?callback=id_168008436280948007039&format=json&lang=ru_RU&token=ab5675e58a9a0ac8fb5c0814d0f2aa24&rspn=0&results=20&origin=jsapi2SearchControl&snippets=businessrating%2F1.x%2Cmasstransit%2F1.x&ask_direct=0&experimental_maxadv=0&apikey=60445215-6d3a-4f88-87fe-8d52b72e5bc9&text=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&ll=23.96608501718749%2C54.18551515033354&spn=42.187499999999986%2C19.676570810688922


searchControl.search('парковка') - данные приходят, но потом область видимости подстраиваться начинает под геообъекты

Answer (score 0):

Итого от техподдержки Я.Карт: "Разработчики сообщили, что как-либо изменить или обойти такое поведение в настоящее время нет возможности."

*Но если кому понадобиться что-то похожее, можно реализовать с помощью платного АПИ поиска по организациям https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosearch/doc/concepts/request.html